# why count the price is not right when the qty equals 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

from this question:
[get all the input value and make an addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486148/get-all-the-input-value-and-make-an-addition)

there is a promotion:

buy 1 each price is 14.37, buy 10 the price is 13.28, buy 20 each price is 10.78.....

now i want to do a counter.http://down123.xxmn.com/count.htm

the counter write the whole price.now, there is something wrong with my code.

if i fill 5 in an input box, then fill 5 in another input box. the whole price isn't 132.8. why?

if i remove a number in an input box, the whole price doesn't change. thank you

the code:

```
var $inputs = jQuery('.liste_couleur_qty li input');
$inputs.keyup(function() {
   var result = 0;
   $inputs.each(function(){
     result += parseInt(this.value, 10);
   });
   var JsonData =[{"price_id":"1","website_id":"0","price_qty":1,"price":"14.37"},
 {"price_id":"2","website_id":"0","price_qty":10,"price":"13.28"},
 {"price_id":"3","website_id":"0","price_qty":20,"price":"10.78"}, 
  {"price_id":"3","website_id":"0","price_qty":50,"price":"9.23"},
   {"price_id":"3","website_id":"0","price_qty":100,"price":"7.91"}
 ]
   var sorted = JsonData.sort(function(a,b){return a.price_qty - b.price_qty;});

var i=0;
while(i < sorted.length && sorted[i].price_qty <= result){i++;} 

var price = sorted[i-1].price;

   price= price*result;

   jQuery('#qtyvalue').html("Total price is " + price);    
});
```

now, when the qty is 9, the right price is 9*14.37. but my counter is not right.

Comment: Are you talking about why it shows 129.32888888888888 instead of 129.33? Or is it something else?

Comment: nope, if i remove a number in an input box, the whole price doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is a method called `.toFixed()`

Try changing the last line that sets your price to

```
jQuery('#qtyvalue').html("Total price is " + price.toFixed(2));
```

and that should work.

---

**Update**:

When you empty any text box, your code stops working since the value is `''` rather than `0`, and can't be added. Update the 5th line of the code to this:

```
result += parseInt((this.value === '' ? 0 : this.value), 10);
```

Comment: ok, thank you. if i remove a number in an input box, the whole price doesn't change. thank you

Comment: your mean below:  jQuery('#qtyvalue').html("Total price is " + price);    
});

Comment: No, below the line of code that has `.keyup()`. In your displayed code here, it would below the 2nd line

Comment: but now  when i using the backpace key to remove the default value 0 in input box, why it can't remove?

Comment: OK, my bad. Didn't think it through. See the updated code